# How to show duplicates on 2 google sheets at the same time?

Tags: google-sheets

This conditional format command shows duplictes on the Sheet1 perfectly:

```
Appliy to range A:A
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1
```

Is it possible make it work with Sheet2 at the same time. I've read that `INDIRECT` could help but I don't understand how to do that.

I tried this with no luck:
[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1` doesn't work at all for me. OTOH, `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A1)` does the trick. I have a favour formula like this: `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A1)>1, "Duplicate", "Unique")`.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to: 1) Explain what you mean by "make it work with Sheet2 at the same time"; 2) Provide some data and demonstrate what a successful outcome would look like. 3) Explain your research about why "...INDIRECT could do that"; if the article had same code, then include that in your question. I urge you to (re)read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tedinoz, I updated the post. The number "3" should be green on both sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to check both sheets for duplicates, you can still use almost the same formula, but you have to put the references into an Indirect statement:

```
=countif(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A"),A1)+countif(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A"),A1)>1
```

as mentioned in [the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: thank you. But it's not working. I updated the post.

Comment: For Sheet1 it should be =countif(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A"),A1)+countif(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"),A1)>1 i.e. you're checking whether A1 occurs again in Sheet1 Col A or Sheet2 Col B. For Sheet 2 =countif(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A"),B1)+countif(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B:B"),B1)>1

Comment: `=COUNTIF({F:F;Sheet2!C:C},F1)>1` seemed to work also when entered in a cell on Sheet1.